# How to wait for Awaited function to finish

Tags: function, async-await

I have a problem when i call an async function that connects to af server that uses a SerialPort to communicate with a ventilation system. The problem is that its working very fine if i make a call the function slowly. By buttons in the Metro interface. But if i programmely want to send 10 commands after each other. eg. 10x `Await Await ReadData("COMMAND")` its failing with the error The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request (800703E3)
I therefore thinks that its not finishing the function before the new one is trying am i correct?

I call with: `DataReceived = Await ReadData(SendCommand)`

And that calls a function

```
Public Shared Async Function SendReceive(SendCommand As String) As Task(Of String)
  'Some code (try/catch) and so on.
  Await _Socket.ConnectAsync(srvHostname, srvPort)

  'Some more code (write to server that talks to ventilation system)
  _writer.WriteString(SendCommand)
  Await _writer.StoreAsync()

  ' More code (read answer from the server from  the ventilation system)
  Dim strReceivedBytes As String = Await _reader.LoadAsync(512)
  Return _Reader.ReadString(strReceivedBytes)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow the problem is only accouring when i click multiple times before the function end. So the solution is to disable the button until function exists.